# Exchanging limit and integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

If $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} |f_m(x)|\rightarrow 0$ for $f$ a Schwartz function (i.e. $f$ is smooth and decays rapidly), is it true that $\|f_m\|_{L^1}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f_m(x)| dx \rightarrow 0$ as $m \rightarrow \infty$?

This seems to be true but I am not sure how to justify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true.
Pick $f_m = \frac{1}{m} 1_{\lbrack 0, m \rbrack }$.

Comment: sorry i meant as m goes to infinity not 0, that was a typo

Comment: Well that was clear.  Try to calculate the norms of the two functions. (I also had a typo)

Comment: even if we smooth out the edges I'm not sure if this is a Schwartz function is it? it doesn't decay faster than any polynomial

Comment: @Sam: Of course it does. It's identically $0$ past $x=m+1$.

Comment: Oh yes, I see now. Thanks